# How to output DATEADD with a specific precision?

Tags: sql, sql-server, dateadd

I have a procedure which is called from external application.
The procedure has a parameter time of bigint type. In the procedure I insert the time to my table to column of 'time' type. To convert bigint to time I use DATEADD:

```
DATEADD(S, @piHMSTime, '19700101')
```

Everything works fine but I get time in my table like this 22:59:57.0000000.
How do I set a needed precision? I need only seconds or maybe 2 digits after point.

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry about it.  The value you are storing uses an internal format.

If you only want to see the time up to seconds, use `convert()`:

```
convert(varchar(8), timecol, 114)
```

If the column is defined as `time`, then the default is to have seven digits of precision for seconds (100 nanoseconds).  If you only want seconds, use `time(0)`:

```
alter table t alter column timecol time(0);
```

Comment: [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/time-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) says the default is seven not six.

Answer (score 0):

The external application is sending you the number of seconds since 1970-01-01.  As long as that doesn't change you can't get more precision.

If you can get the external application to pass you milliseconds since 1970-01-01, you can use the function shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53767909/epoch-conversion-to-datetime-in-sql).